# Fql multiquery executing in graph explorer but not in c# .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-fql

I have the following Fql query:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q={"query1":"SELECT  uid2  FROM  friend  WHERE  uid1=me()","query2":"SELECT uid ,  name ,  pic_square , affiliations , birthday_date , sex , relationship_status , hometown_location , current_location , education_history , work_history , contact_email  FROM  user  WHERE (sex='male') AND uid  IN  (SELECT  uid2  FROM #query1)"}
```

This works fine in graph explorer, however it doesn't work in c#; I get an Http Badrequest error

My query is as follows:

```
"fql?q={'query1':'SELECT+uid2+FROM+friend+WHERE+uid1=me()','query2':'SELECT+uid,name,pic_square,affiliations,birthday_date,sex,relationship_status,hometown_location,current_location,education_history,work_history,contact_email+FROM+user+WHERE+(sex='male')+AND+uid+IN+(SELECT+uid2+FROM+#query1)'}";
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var fb = new Facebook.FacebookClient(token);
dynamic result = fb.Query(
    "SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()",
    "SELECT uid, name, pic_square, affiliations, birthday_date, sex, relationship_status, hometown_location, current_location, education_history, work_history, contact_email" + 
    " FROM user WHERE (sex='male') AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM #query0)"
);
```

The naming convention starts with index 0 rather than index 1 as in other languages. The above code works, I've run it in C# and the results are good.

Comment: What namepspaces have u imported. It does not detect FacebookClient in my case

Comment: I'm using v 5.4 of the SDK.  It should work just fine with the 6.0's that are the latest versions.

Comment: What version are you running?